# Determine Datatype of Parameter to SQL Query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

In a C# application. I want to be able to retrieve the expected parameters to a query and their meta data.

For example if there was a query like

```
select * from customer where name = @customer_name
```

Is it possible to determine the expected data type of the @customer_name field from the query.  I know I can retrieve other meta data about the resultant columns using

```
DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable()
```

I need to be able to perform a similar action with the parameters.  I'm open to using 3rd party providers if they can solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a query in a string like the one you have in your question, then you can't.

But if you have a command object and have added your parameters then you  can find the `DbType` like:

```
foreach (SqlParameter parameter in command.Parameters)
    Console.WriteLine(parameter.DbType);
```

But you can only do that **after the parameters have been added** to the command.

Comment: It's a bit of a chicken and egg situation. I'm trying to determine the parameters from the query then prompt a user for values in controls correct for their datatype.

Comment: @keitn, I am not sure you can do that, the only thing that comes to my mind *(right now)* is to extract table name from the query , get the table schema from the database and then compare data types of columns with the one in query...

Comment: The problem is that there could be joins/temporary tables etc. used. I think the best I can do is use text parsing, far from ideal I know but I can't think of any other approach.